# How to control the format to export discriminant analysis results to word by using asdoc in Stata?

Tags: export, stata, cpu-word

I want to export the results of a discriminant analysis by using asdoc in stata.

I want to show as follows.

1. three Three Decimal Digits.
2. compress the table to fit into a page of the word.

However, the format of the results is horrible. I use dec(3) but not working. I read the "help asdoc" in Stata, but it all about regression.

[image]

Does anyone know how to export the total results of discriminant analysis to Word with nice format?

Thank you in advance.

The following is the sample code and asdoc code that I use.

```
    input area  Revenue age child_number    grocery_expense credit_card     exercise_week   social_week
1   99336   76  1   22453   5   3   1
1   59092   75  4   16995   6   1   3
1   68614   49  0   37709   0   7   5
1   84805   55  3   21642   0   3   1
1   66138   41  3   10490   2   4   7
1   90238   43  2   30254   5   6   4
1   60466   49  2   18136   1   0   4
1   46575   64  0   25053   6   6   7
2   97811   40  4   36925   4   6   5
2   61862   40  0   14480   5   5   6
2   58071   73  0   24754   4   0   1
2   42539   66  2   19903   3   1   6
2   62074   56  3   12560   3   3   7
2   71619   34  2   24523   6   3   6
2   51281   74  2   23625   4   6   3
3   40990   25  3   38943   4   7   4
3   44567   73  2   39898   1   4   7
3   73586   42  2   20159   0   2   3
3   44907   44  3   31378   1   1   6
3   79352   20  3   39968   6   6   1
3   55647   50  1   27122   0   3   6
3   80943   43  1   15177   2   7   4
3   88892   77  2   22537   4   2   7
4   91735   74  3   27505   0   5   2
4   61224   60  5   12374   5   1   0
4   72192   68  4   36817   2   6   1
4   87486   59  0   34846   6   5   1
4   53131   52  4   12584   5   1   1
4   49083   33  5   30652   3   0   5
4   47408   49  0   28938   1   6   0
4   74647   52  2   15291   0   5   6
5   81643   37  0   37993   2   4   2
5   42371   46  1   33436   6   5   4
5   74074   24  3   16618   5   6   7
5   63502   34  3   19887   1   4   3
5   86779   31  5   37290   6   3   4
5   45842   45  5   20383   2   1   5
5   59835   42  5   30708   4   2   1
5   60486   38  2   36167   3   6   2
5   49099   58  0   13157   4   3   7
5   71692   37  5   36317   4   6   3
5   91406   45  5   12451   5   7   1
6   42742   48  1   39088   5   2   0
6   54538   21  2   19657   0   7   3
6   49323   69  4   37173   5   5   5
6   50053   54  4   32193   2   7   7
6   99139   48  1   14647   4   4   1
6   97908   26  0   14319   6   1   4
6   46504   27  1   39478   4   6   2
6   92330   28  3   23676   1   3   0
6   93926   34  3   10871   1   3   3
6   81890   51  2   16914   1   0   1
6   86679   79  1   35967   2   7   6
6   43783   67  2   31009   2   5   0
6   76770   66  5   13220   6   6   7
6   91160   67  2   29346   6   0   3
end
    
asdoc candisc  Revenue  age child_number    grocery_expense credit_card     exercise_week   social_week , group (area) dec(3)
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this question on Statalist because Attaullah Shah, the author, hangs out there, not here.

Comment: Thank you Wouter for the information. I will do that.

Comment: Posting on Statalist is good advice, but once you have done that you should give a precise URL so that people can check for answers there https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1569559-how-to-control-the-format-to-export-discriminant-analysis-results-to-word-by-using-asdoc Conversely, Statalist etiquette is also to explain about cross-posting.

Comment: The correct code is `asdoc candisc Revenue age child_number grocery_expense credit_card exercise_week, group(area)`. With the latest version of `asdoc` installed Stata respects the default `3`-digit output setting and with `dec()` you can indeed change the number of digits. So my guess is that you do not have installed the latest version of `asdoc` on your computer and you need to update it. Then all you have to do is change the page orientation in Word to landscape for the table to fit in one page.

Answer (score 0):

The [asdoc](https://fintechprofessor.com/2018/01/31/asdoc/) program does not have built-in support for the `candisc` command. The output you see from the [asdoc](https://fintechprofessor.com/2018/01/31/asdoc/) for `candisc` is what asdoc converts the Stata log output to a table. However, the table is not properly formatted in such cases, neither the decimal points are controlled by asdoc. If you really need a well-formatted table, with all controls, you can request it either on the [asdoc](https://fintechprofessor.com/forums/forum/asdoc/) forum or on [asdocx](https://asdocx.com/forums/forum/asdocx-forum/) forum. Requests on asdocx forums are usually prioritized, due to the fact that asdoc is free, and asdocx is its premium version.

Please note I am the author of both the packages, and my recommendation for [asdocx](https://asdocx.com/) is biased for two reasons: (1) asdocx is a paid product available for $9.99 (2) I think asdocx is more flexible and aligns well with the demand of many Stata users, hence it will receive all my attention for future updates.